# How to create a file when working with threads in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

Have a look at this code :

```
import threading
import time

def my_inline_function(number):
    #do some stuff
    download_thread = threading.Thread(target=function_that_writes, args=number)
    download_thread.start()
    #continue doing stuff
    i = 0

    while(i < 10000):
        print str(i) + " : Main thread"
        time.sleep(1)
        i = i + 1


def function_that_writes(number):
    i = number

    file = open("dummy.txt", 'w')

    while (i < 10000):
        string = str(i) + " : child thread"
        file.write(string)
        time.sleep(1)
    file.close()

my_inline_function(5)
function_that_writes(5)
```

With does `my_inline_function()`, which starts a thread, not create a file?

But when I am calling a `function_that_writes(...)` directly, which is not running in a thread, it is able to create a file.

Why am I getting this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to supply your argument as a tuple `args=(number,)`:

```
download_thread = threading.Thread(target=function_that_writes, args=(number,))
```

The exception is pretty clear here:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mike/anaconda/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Users/mike/anaconda/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
TypeError: function_that_writes() argument after * must be an iterable, not int
```

Comment: Yes you are right, but why am I not getting an error?

Comment: Are you running your script from command line? What OS are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu and I am running this from pycharm

Comment: Try from the command line. Maybe PyCharm is not showing you the error message. Maybe it is in another PyCharm window.

Comment: and why is comma(,) given in "args=(number,)" even if there is only one argument.

Comment: Yes in command line it is showing an error but it hasn't stopped executing script. The main thread is doing its work. (i.e. it is printing [number] : Main Thread)

Comment: The main thread continues even though there is an exception in another thread. You need to provide the arguments as a tuple like `(arg1, arg2)`. If you have only one  argument, you still need a tuple, i.e. `(arg1,)`. You need this comma to make it a tuple.